# I am getting trouble when I use command java -jni HelloWorld

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I am learning how to use jni(java native interface), and I follows steps presented by a blog. I have created a java file named 'HelloWorld.java',content as following:

```
public class HelloWorld { 
    public native void displayHelloWorld(); 
    static { 
        System.loadLibrary("HelloWorldImpl"); 
    } 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        HelloWorld helloWorld = new HelloWorld(); 
        helloWorld.displayHelloWorld(); 
    } 
}
```

then I execute this command:

```
javac HelloWorld
```

there's no error happened,  but when I execute this command:

```
javah -jni HelloWorld
```

then I get a error:

```
can't find class "HelloWorld"
```

I am sure, this directory has the HelloWorld.class file that have been compile.

the dev:

```
jdk8
windows 10 64bits
```

I have google for a long time and asked my classmates who are successful using  same steps, but cannot deal with this problem, something was wrong in my laptop?
anyone could help me?Thank a lot.

Comment: In what package is `HelloWorld` located?

Comment: no package, just a simple directory, and run cmd at current dir

Comment: You checked that file `.\HelloWorld.class` exists. Have you tried `javah -jni -cp . HelloWorld` ?

Comment: A better title would help. "Getting into trouble" doesn't tell anyone anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make sure to use packages. It is not mandatory, but it simplifies things.

Then, after you have compiled your java code, make sure to use:

```
javah -jni -cp . HelloWorld
```

You can alternatively create header files in some location

```
javah -jni -d c -cp . HelloWorld
# -d c     -> header files will be created inside directory called "c"
```

I'd also suggest to compile classes into some subdirectory as well:

```
javac -d target HelloWorld.java
# compiled classes will be inside "target" dir
# then, you can call javah this way
javah -jni -d c -cp target HelloWorld
```

Take a look here for full sample with super easy code:

http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-001/

Have fun with JNI!